# specific page redirect to corresponding mobile page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that works with other circumstances but is giving me problems I guess due to the `window.locaton`. Please help I need to redirect users to specific mobile pages depending on the desktop page.

```js
function mon() {
  if ($('body').is('.mon')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function tue() {
  if ($('body').is('.tue')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function wed() {
  if ($('body').is('.wed')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}


function detectmob() {
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

if (detectmob() && mon()) {
  window.location = "../m/days/mon.html";
} else if (detectmob() && tue()) {
  window.location = "../m/days/tue.html";
} else if (detectmob() && wed()) {
  window.location = "../m/days/wed.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake

```html
<body class="mon">

  <script src="jquip.min.js"></script><!--increase load time instead of jquery.min-->
  
  <script>
    function mon() {
      if ($('body').is('.mon')) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    function tue() {
      if ($('body').is('.tue')) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    function wed() {
      if ($('body').is('.wed')) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }


    function detectmob() {
      if (screen.width <= 800) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (detectmob() && mon()) {
      window.location = "../m/days/mon.html";
    } else if (detectmob() && tue()) {
      window.location = "../m/days/tue.html";
    } else if (detectmob() && wed()) {
      window.location = "../m/days/wed.html";
    }
  </script>
```

working fine